# migrating logins to another subscription in azure

Tags: sql, azure

Is there a way to migrate logins, including their sid and passwords, to a master on a server on another subscription in azure?  There seems to be a couple ways to do this on-prem to on-prem but haven't found a way to migrate logins across subscriptions from azure sql to azure sql

Comment: Fairly sure (not certain) it can do cross subscription, but ADF (azure data factory) can move data from one place to another.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring an Azure subscription to a different Azure AD directory is a complex process that must be carefully planned and executed. Many Azure services require security principals (identities) to operate normally or even manage other Azure resources.

Steps to prepare for the transfer are in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription